# synchronization at block level

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I need to clear some points regarding synchronization at block level.

suppose following synchronization blocks are **in a same method** of a class:

```
class A{

some_method(){

//BLOCK1
synchronized(OBJ1){
shared code...
}

//BLOCK2
synchronized(OBJ1){
shared code...
}

//BLOCK3
synchronized(OBJ2){
shared code...
}
}

}
```

Following queries:

1) IS this right that if one thread enters block1 by obtaining lock on OBJ1, then no other thread can enter into Block2 as long as first thread holds lock on OBJ1, but other thread can run block3 simultaneously ?

2)Does first thread need to obtain lock on OBJ1 again if enters block2 after completing block1?

3)if first thread calls some code in block2, from block1 then will it have to release the lock on OBJ1 obtain during first block execution and again obtain it OR same lock obtain during first block will work?

Now suppose block1 is in a method of one class and blockk2 and 3 are in a method **of some other class**

4)Same as in point 1 holds true as synchronization is happening by obtaining lock on  some third class obj (OBJ1,OBJ2)?

Comment: [Java Tutorials: Synchronized Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, it's correct.
2. Yes, since the block is synchronized on OBJ1
3. I don't understand what you mean. If what you're asking is "are locks reentrant?", then yes. A thread which already has a lock on an object can enter another block synchronized on the same object.
4. Yes. Where the code is doesn't matter. What matters is if the thread has the lock or not.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, if a thread holds the OBJ1 lock then no other thread can acquire the same lock

2) Yes, the lock needs to be acquired again because it will have been released at the end of block 1

3) No, a thread will not block on a lock that it already holds

4) Yes

Answer (score 0):

1) YES
2) Yes, since it is outside the BLOCK1.

3) Same lock holds (i.e. already acquired) for nested locking as this one.

> > Now suppose block1 is in a method of one class and blockk2 and 3 are in a method of some other class
> >     
> > >> Ans: Results won't differ as far as the lock object is the same object in the memory.

4) Yes